# Fix ticks distances in an sns heatmap - differing number of trials on y axis

Tags: python, heatmap, yticks

I'm plotting a 2d heatmap across 3 different conditions (so 3 separate plots), dimensions trials x time. X axis is fixed size across conditions. However each condition has a different number of trials (different number of ticks on the y axis). By default, all my plots across all conditions have the same height, and that's not ideal - i would like the height of the plot to be affected by the number of trials (y axis). That is, I would like to somehow "fix" the distances between ticks on the y axis, so that plots will be different heights depending on the y axis, and the little "rectangles" inside of the plots will be same size as a result. I haven't found any functionality to do that, set_aspect does not quite do the job... Would be so grateful for any info!

```
        for state in states:
                # Set plot parameters
                plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))  # Set the figure size
                ax = sns.heatmap(heatmap_array, cmap='rocket', cbar=False)  
             
                
                plt.xlabel('Time')
                plt.ylabel('Trials')
                plt.tight_layout()
              
                # Display the plot
                plt.show()
```